# Can’t remove kernel extension

Tags: macos, kernel-extension

I’m trying to remove the wifi kernel extensions from macOS in recovery mode, but the file is always being created again after reboot. I tried

```
kmutil trigger-panic-medic --volume-root /Volumes/<YourVolumeName>
```

but also didn’t work. I tried to disable SIP too. I removed the files using rm. Is there a way to permanently disable wifi kernel extensions?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming related question but rather a macOS sysadmin/power user question, so belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Presumably this is one of the built-in kexts that ships with macOS? Apple really doesn't want you messing with system internals anymore in recent versions of macOS.

Comment: Thanks, already solved it. I was able to permanently delete a wifi kext that was getting me kernel panics because of a hardware problem.